# rewriteRule doesn't redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have strange situation. I have one site that has framework and same site has wordpress installed on subfolder. The subfolder is named wp. I want all requests to wp/blog to be replaced with blog, but in same time the links with wp/blog to be inactive. I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^blog/([^'"]+)?$  /wp/blog/$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^wp/blog/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

So when i have address like http://mydomain.com/blog/test 
it works and shows the wordpress content, but http://mydomain.com/wp/blog/test
shows the content too.
Why second rewriteRule doesn't work? 
I removed first RewriteRule and again second one doesn't redirect.

The main idea of this is to hide "wp" from the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable to force 301 redirect as:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+wp/(blog/[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(blog/[^'"]+)?$ /wp/$1 [PT]
```

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't redirect somehow. Even if i remove all conditions and leave only RewriteRule ^wp /%1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Make sure this 301 is very first rule. Also I believe it is redirecting but WP is probably forcing `/wp/` back. Can you open this URL in firebug and check Net tab to verify this. FInally you can try changing WP permalink setting to also remove `/wp/` from site and home URLs.

Comment: Nope :( no redirect. Status 200 instead 301 I put this row right below RewriteEngine On

Comment: If there is .htaccess in `/wp/` then it needs to be placed in `/wp/.htaccess` AND if there is `/wp/blog/.htaccess` also then it needs to be there.